# Getting an error 'NameError: name 'issue' is not defined' while using JIRA API for Python

Tags: python, nameerror, jira-rest-api

I am new to python and I am trying to fetch a ticket from the jira tool using the REST API. Eventually, I would want to fetch all reopened tickets and print. I am able to login to the site but getting the NameError after that. Appreciate the help.Following is the code.

```
from jira.client import JIRA

def connect_to_jira():
    jira_options = {'server': 'jira.com'}
    try:
       jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    except Exception as e:
       jira = None
    return jira

jira = connect_to_jira
issue = jira.issue('jira-8329')
print (issue)
```

Comment: It's impossible for the code snippet above to return that error, `NameError` is thrown when you make reference to a variable not defined. That snippet will cause a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'issue'` because your `jira` variable is an alias for `connect_to_jira` function, and you are accessing the `issue` attribute on it.

Comment: @ChristianWitts Please be careful when editing. You "helpfully" adding parentheses after that function call in OP's code may have completely obscured the actual issue, and invalidated the top comment which is probably the correct answer!

Comment: @memoselyk Could you please elaborate on what you want me to change in the code. Are you talking about local and global variables?

Comment: @RakeshNittur `jira = connect_to_jira` gives you a **reference** to that function. If you want to call it (get the return value), you need `jira = connect_to_jira()` (note the parentheses). What you have gives the function a shorter name, which would only be handy if later you wanted to call `jira()` and get the same result as calling `connect_to_jira()`.

Comment: @RakeshNittur, `NameError` is caused by using a variable which was not defined previously, sometimes it's a logic error, but others could be a typo. In your code snippet, `issue` variable only appears in the last two lines, it's assignment `issue = jira.issue('jira-8329')` and it's usage `print (issue)`; and the definition happens before the usage so that error is not possible with this code.

Comment: @memoselyk, I got it. Thanks a lot.